# How to get all variables in scope assigned under a `with statement` in Python?

Tags: python, class, scope, namespaces, with-statement

**Is there any way to do a `with statement` and then any variable assigned under that context would be record**ed?

Essentially what I'm trying to do is make some sort of `class` that I can put before a big block of code and say if not all of the variables under this `with statement` are in the `namespace` then run all these commands but this is the first step.

Below is some pseudo code to illustrate my question:

```
class CustomClass(object):
    pass

with CustomClass() as cc:
    a = 0
    b = 1
# print(cc.scope)
# ["a","b"]
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can’t just make a subclass instead of using `with`? What are you trying to accomplish by using `with`?

Comment: It was inspired from `pymc3` when the model is instantiated.  I wasn't sure how else it could be implemented but definitely open to ideas!  Thanks. Here is an example at [code block In: 4](https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/getting_started)